# Fluent Validation - Custom Guid Validator not triggering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have a custom FleuntValidation validationrule that checks if a Guid is valid;

```
 public static class GuidValidator
{
    private static Regex isGuid = new Regex(@"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    public static bool IsGuid(string candidate)
    {
        if (candidate != null)
        {
            if (isGuid.IsMatch(candidate))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to use this to check a Guid Property for a valid Guid and then return a custom error message.

```
RuleFor(x => x.ShiftId).Must(guid => GuidValidator.IsGuid(guid.ToString())).WithMessage("StopShift.ShiftId.GuidNotValid()");
```

However, my rule does not get hit, because i guess the Guid is not valid and some built in check runs before it. How would i disable the built-in check so my custom rule gets reached?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what your stack looks like. A `Guid` will not be instantiated with an "invalid" value.

If you want to cater for a use case where the value in question can either be a valid or invalid `Guid` I suggest you model it as a string.

e.g.

```
[Validator(typeof(FooRequestValidator))]
public class FooRequest
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FooRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<FooRequest>
{
    public FooRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Bar)
            .Must(ValidateBar).WithErrorCode("Not a guid");
    }

    private bool ValidateBar(string bar)
    {
        return Guid.TryParse(bar, out _);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Property in the class is a non-nullable Guid.

```
public Guid ProductId {get;set;}
```

Here is what I use

```
RuleFor(product => product.ProductId).Must(BeAValidGuid).When(product => product.ProductId != null);
```

With the Custom Rule

```
private bool BeAValidGuid(Guid unValidatedGuid)
    {
        try
        {
            if(unValidatedGuid != Guid.Empty && unValidatedGuid != null )
            {
                if (Guid.TryParse(unValidatedGuid.ToString(), out Guid validatedGuid))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```